# why does Linux only boot on my computer when I add pci=noacpi in grub? Must I replace my laptop? Is it serious enough?

Tags: linux, grub, acpi

I have tried Ubuntu and Linux Mint and both of them only boot when `acpi=off` or `pci=noacpi`. What is this irq and pci scannning ? Someone told me to replace my laptop (it is in warranty period). I am using HP 13-b202tu.

Answer (score 4):

No need to replace laptop. I have the same laptop and the same problem. Instead of disabling acpi (and rendering your wifi adapter, lcd backlight brightness, keyboard or touchpad useless) try using `acpi_osi=` as a kernel parameter. You can try `acpi_osi="Linux"` but the empty paramter one works for me.

As for answering to your question, I'll be explaining in laymen terms. ACPI is Advanced Configuration and Power Interface. As the name suggests it deals with the power management of the components. It actually brings the control of the power management in the hands of the Operating System instead of the platform specific firmware. So ACPI contains data about the components which are to be loaded before Operating system starts. Hardware vendors often use these as a workaround for bugs in Windows. So such a hack work for windows and fails for linux :). That is the reason you can only boot with acpi off.

For the other part of your question, IRQ(InterruptReQuest) is a type of message sent to the CPU to get its attention and both IRQ and PCI scanning is a way to find out the above said components for ACPI to function.

Answer (score -1):

It is rather normal relax, having problems with Linux and hardware is not out of ordinary, and so much more in laptops. What can be done often is planning ahead, and buying more compatible hardware.

I am not much fond of HP, Lenovo and Dell products because of white listing of hardware, namely wifi and ethernet cards in the BIOS. (i.e. if you want to change the wifi card, you have to pay extra for it to have the HP sticker)

One another thing is returning the product when new (i.e. here by law we have between 14 and 30 days depending on the place and the way we bought it and paid for it), but after the 30 days are over we won't be able to return it because of compatibility problems with linux.

I would look at other brands, Acer for instance.

As for desktops, nowadays my server/desktop at home is a Linux/ARM server.

Comment: have a macbook pro. They are pricey. The hardware is good, OS/X is not as stable as it used to be, but it is better than the alternative (Windows). I would look at other brands, Acer for instance, if not wanting to pay the Apple tag price.

Comment: What's to say an Acer or an Apple might not need a boot option to circumvent a firmware bug/feature in the future? Does this really answer the OPs question?

Comment: This is called planning ahead. If you are buying for Linux, you look up the compatibility list of the included hardware.